# many-to-many retrieve only one row

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a relationship between two domain class: **User** and **Bank**, user has many of bank and bank has many of user, the result table I call it as `mm_user_banks` that keep both table IDs for MM relationship.

```
class User {

    String name
    String password
    Date createdAt = new Date()
    Date loginAt

    static hasMany = [banks:Bank]

    static fetchMode = [banks: 'eager']

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        banks joinTable: [name: 'mm_user_banks', key: 'mm_user_id']
    }
}
```

and Bank...

```
class Bank {

    Long id
    String name

    static belongsTo = User
    static hasMany = [users:User]

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
        users joinTable: [name: 'mm_user_banks', key: 'mm_bank_id'], lazy: false
    }
}
```

I can save users with banks as well, but the problem is when I try to retrieve bank list from an user instance and it only fetch one row even if there is more than one row for this user in `mm_user_banks` table.

E.g:

```
User u = new User(name: 'user', password: 'pwd')
u.addToBanks(Bank.findById(1))
u.addToBanks(Bank.findById(2))
u.addToBanks(Bank.findById(3))

u.save(flush: true)
```

In database it is OK, fetching 3 rows, but when I get the user and see its bank list:

```
def user = User.findById(1) //OK

println "Size ${user.banks?.size()}" //only 1??? How?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it out - "user.banks?.size()" returns "3". Are you sure that data in DB is OK?

Anyway, if you want to use eager fetching for collections then define it in "mapping" of User class (instead of "fetchMode" static field):

```
static mapping = {
    banks joinTable: [name: 'mm_user_banks', key: 'mm_user_id'], fetch: 'join'
}
```

in Bank class use **fetch: 'join'** in mapping instead of lazy: false

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, Sergei, but didn't worked out.

I fixed it in an ugly way, but this is was my remaining way out.

I created another domain class to mapping the MM table, so I did a `mm_user_banks` class. I use it to fetch records from bank or user and worked OK. To save banks for a user I actually do it in the old way as well, not changed from that. I guess this mighty not be the best way, but like I said, worked out.

I've tried "fetch: 'join'" and "lazy: false" and "static fetchMode = [banks: 'eager']" without success.

The new domain class is:

```
class UserBanks {

    User user
    Bank bank

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        table name: 'mm_user_banks'
        user column: 'mm_user_id'
        bank column: 'mm_bank_id'
    }
}
```

Comment: One last comment: make sure in DB the MM table has an ID even with bank or user IDs and this ID is primary and somehow incrementable. I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem but in my case I had another relation between my equivalents to User and the Bank. This made the hasMany statement to use the wrong relation to map the many to many relation. In my case it was solved by adding a mappedBy statement to the relation:

```
class Bank{
    ...
    static mappedBy=[users:'banks']
    ...
}
```

and

```
class User{
    ...
    static mappedBy=[banks:'users']
    ...
}
```

or as it was in my case, since it was a uni-directional relation:

```
class ArticleGroup {

    String name
    static hasMany = [articles:Article]

    static mappedBy = [articles: 'none']

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false, blank:false, unique:true, maxSize:100)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'article_group'
        sort 'name'

        articles joinTable: [name:'article_group_article', key: 'articleGroup_id', column:'article_id'], fetch: 'join'

    }
```